# How to break a long line in Lua

Tags: lua

```
Util = {
  scale = function (x1, x2, x3, y1, y3) return (y1) + ( (y2) -  (y1)) * \
        ( (x2) -  (x1)) / ( (x3) -  (x1)) end

}

print(Util.scale(1, 2, 3, 1, 3))
```

What is the proper syntax for breaking a long line in Lua?

Comment: [code convention](https://github.com/luarocks/lua-style-guide)

Comment: Lua syntax doesn't have a concept of "line", so there is no difference between space and newline, both are separators.  You can replace any (syntactical!) space with a newline.  Backslashed newlines are used only inside quoted literal string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your particular case, the convention would be ...

```
Util = {
   scale = function (x1, x2, x3, y1, y3) 
       return (y1) + ( (y2) -  (y1)) * ( (x2) -  (x1)) / ( (x3) -  (x1)) 
   end

}
```

Where the break is on statements
Further breaking could be done if the multiplication needs to be split with

```
Util = {
   scale = function (x1, x2, x3, y1, y3) 
       return (y1) + ( (y2) -  (y1)) * 
               ( (x2) -  (x1)) / ( (x3) -  (x1)) 
   end

}
```

With the multiplication token used to split the line. By leaving a token at the end of the line, the parser requires more input to complete the expression, so looks onto the next line.

Lua is generally blind to line characters, they are just white-space.  However, there are cases where there can be differences, and I would limit line breaks to places where there is an obvious need for extra data.

> > ```
> >  a = f
> >  (g).x(a)
> > ```

Is a specific case where it could be treated as `a = f(g).x(a)` or `a = f` and `(g).x(a)`

By breaking after a token which requires continuation, you ensure you are working with the parser.

Comment: Do you think that without having a multiplication symbol at the end of a line, parser would stop the expression there?

Comment: There are specific cases in the manual which highlight the lack of significance of a line break, but there are cases where the line break has significance.

Comment: You could also put the opening parenthesis of the next operand at the end of the line.  In that case the parser will *always* continue scanning.

Comment: Could you include whether there is actual LUA operators for this, (semicolon, _ , or whatever?).  Thanks!